# Updating data from protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm building a microservice system with multiple disconnected components, and I'm currently trying to find out how to implement knowing which fields on an object should be updated based on the `protobuf` data provided.

The flow is this:

1. The client sends a JSON-request to an API.
2. The API translates the JSON-data into a `protobuf` struct, which is then sent along to the microservice responsible for handling it.
3. The microservice receives the data from the API and performs any action on it, in this case, I'm trying to change a single value in a MySQL table, such as a client's email address.

Now, the problem I have is that since `protobuf` (understandably) doesn't allow pointers, the `protobuf` object will contain zero-values for everything not provided. This means that if a customer wants to update their email address, I can't know if they also set `IncludeInMailLists` to `false` - or if it was simply not provided (having its zero-value) and shouldn't change.

The question is: how will I - from the protobuf object - know if a value is expressively set to 0, or just not provided?

My current solution is pretty much having a special `UpdateCustomer`-object which also has an array of `Fields` specifying which fields the microservice should care about, but it feels like bad solution.

Someone must have solved this better already. How should I implement it?

Comment: I've not used `protobuf` myself, but wouldn't it work to implement the `Unmarshaler` and `Marshaler` interfaces for your structs and handle the absence of values there? Unfortunately the docs don't contain examples. https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Unmarshaler EDIT: You'd have to do this on both ends obviously because Go probably sends the `zero` values of your struct.

Comment: Check out protobufs field masks, they help to specify what's changed.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask
https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/225

Comment: The naive solution would be to also send a list (derived at the json2proto conversion) that tells you what fields have been supplied in the json.

Comment: Or you can introduce values that indicate that the value has been set, but is empty: {"user":{"email":""}} -> User.Email = "EMPTY". This however tends to bite you in the tail very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your input, guys! @Zak, FieldMaps definitely seems to be the right way to go. I'll start by reading up on that and get back to you when I understand them better. Thanks!

Comment: @Zak, could you promote your comment to an answer?  It is definitely the correct way to go.

Answer (score 9):

Protobufs field masks are one way.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/225

But if you are using [grpc](https://grpc.io/) then there's a (sort of) built in way.

### Grpc wrappers

Since proto3 (protobufs v3) there's been no distinction between a primitive that is not set, and a primitive that's been set to the "zero value" (false, 0, "", etc).

Instead you can use objects or in protobufs language a "message", as objects can be nil / null. You've not mentioned what language you are working in but hopefully these examples make sense.

Given an RPC service such as:

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service Users {
    rpc UpdateUser(UpdateUserRequest) returns (UpdateUserResponse)
}

message UpdateUserRequest {
    int32 user_id = 1;
    google.protobuf.StringValue email = 2;
}

message UpdateUserResponse {}
```

**Note** the `import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";` is important.
It given you access to the google protobufs wrappers [source code here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto). These are not objects that have methods that allow you to test for presence.

Grpc generated code in java gives you methods such as `.hasEmail()` which returns `true` if the value is present. The getter on an unset value will still return you the zero value. I think the golang version uses pointers that you can test for nil instead of an explicit `hasX()` method.

More info / discussion in this [github issue](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/359)

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted... it seems like the google WKT `*Value` fields are the proper way to address this. Any reason why this shouldn't be so?

Comment: was downvoted before the post was properly worded / filled out. Originally just contained links to issues.

Comment: gotcha... you were squatting! I'm going to upvote this despite your insidious behavior, because I think it's the proper answer ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this strategy doesn't work for repeated (slice) fields OOTB. You have to create new wrapper types as needed.